# How to format strings to print in a file with F#

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

This code is printing float numbers in the file with this format *f,ffffff* (with comma) and the numbers are in a row, but I need to print it like this *f.ffffff* (with dot) and after each number skip a line, so each number has its own line. Any ideas on how do I do it?

CODE EDITED

```
module writeFiles = 
    let (w:float[]) = [|-1.3231725; 1.052134922; 1.23082055; 1.457748868; -0.3481141253; -0.06886428466; -1.473392229; 0.1103078722; -1.047231857; -2.641890652; -1.335060286; -0.9839854216; 0.1844535984; 3.087001584; -0.008467130841; 1.175365466; 1.637297522; 5.557832631; -0.2906445452; -0.4052301538; 1.766454088; -2.604325471; -1.807107036; -2.471407376; -2.204730614;|]
    let write secfilePath= 
        for j in 0 .. 24 do
            let z = w.[j].ToString()
            File.AppendAllText(secfilePath, z)
            //File.AppendAllLines(secfilePath, z)
            done
```

Comment: What is `filterMod`? Can you reduce the sample code so that it's self-contained and compilable? http://sscce.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is couple things that could be done better in your code.

1. You're opening the file over and over again every time you add a number
2. `z` does not need to be mutable
3. You can pass format pattern and/or culture to `ToString` call
4. You can iterate over `filterMod.y` instead of `for` loop and array indexer access

I would probably go with something more like

```
module writeFiles = 
    let write secfilePath= 
        let data = filterMod.y
                   |> Array.map (fun x -> x.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        File.AppendAllLines(secfilePath, data)
```

It prepares an array of strings, where every number of `filterMod.y` gets formatted using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, which will make it use `.` as decimal separator. And later on it uses `AppendAllLines` to write the whole array to the file at once, where every element will be written in a separate line.